# Debian 8.5.0 netinstall ISO. Can't find. Jigdo makes is corrupted

Tags: debian, debian-jessie

I am trying to find the ISO for Debian 8.5.0 Netinstall, AMD-64. I found http://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/cdimage/archive/ this page which contains only a "jigdo" option to download the iso. I downloaded and installed jigdo on my ubuntu (latest version). I tried to use `jigdo-lite` from the command line, and inserted the http://cdimage.debian.org/mirror/cdimage/archive/8.5.0/amd64/jigdo-cd/debian-8.5.0-amd64-netinst.jigdo jigdo URL. All is successfull but when I am trying to install this on a computer, I get tens of "corrupted" errors.

Where can I find the ISO?? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can find Debian 8.5.0 AMD64 netinst, here: http://ftp.cae.tntech.edu/debian-cd/debian-8.5.0-amd64-netinst.iso

**EDIT - OTHER MIRRORS:**

- http://ftp.cae.tntech.edu/debian-cd/
- http://ftp.riken.go.jp/Linux/debian/debian-cdimage/archive/
- http://snapshot.debian.org/ (a bit hard to find, use left menu)

Comment: I continue to get the same error while installing. What could be the cause?

Comment: Are you using USB or CD/DVD? What software do you use?

Comment: Trying to burn on usb with Win32 Disk Imager

Comment: Please "burn" it manually: `dd if=./debian-8.5.0-amd64-netinst.iso of=/dev/sdb`

Comment: Worked. Thanks!!! So jigdo is working too. The problem was the method of burning. Really tried a lot of burning methods.